# RewriteRule .htaccess not working

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am facing problem with `mod_rewrite ^(.+)$ /article.php?pname=$1 [L,QSA]` is working fine but after that other RewriteRule dont work i dont know why ... here is my code

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /article.php?pname=$1 [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /cat.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

If i remove `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /article.php?pname=$1 [L,QSA]` other RewriteRule  works but it dont work with this, how can both work together ?
Please help

Comment: Because last line has lowest priority.

Comment: @M1K1O How can i fix that .. please

Comment: Why is `ErrorDocument` there? IIRC, only `RewriteRule` or `RewriteCond` should come after `RewriteCond`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ cat.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ article.php?pname=$1 [L,QSA]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Thx it worked but if i am trying to add 'RewriteRule ^latest-tech-news/(.*)$ latest.php$1 [QSA,L]' its not working with above code how can i add that too .... please help

Comment: **Just below** category rule you can have this rule: `RewriteRule ^latest-tech-news/(.*)$ latest.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]` Also it will help if you tell me what is your internal URI for this rule.

Answer (score 1):

Simple change order, from:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /article.php?pname=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /cat.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /cat.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /article.php?pname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Because `(.+)` will rewrite everithing including `cat.php`. So when you are trying to access `cat.php?name=someName` you will get `/article.php?pname=cat.php%3Fname%3DsomeName`.

You should do following:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(cat\.php|someFolder|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /article.php?pname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or even this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !-f
RewriteRule !(cat\.php|someFolder|robots\.txt)$ /article.php?pname=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`robots.txt` should not to be rewrited.

Comment: it give 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Do not forget, last line will rewrite also `cat.php` to `article.php?pname=cat.php`

Comment: How can i fix that ;(

Comment: Thx for help ... but it still dont work ;( ... i dont know where is the problem ... ur last solution just give one article for all links ;(